# Ant not loading salesforce task definitions?

Tags: bash, ant, salesforce

**The Question**

I'm trying to use the Force.com Migration Tool (a custom ant library) on a linux box and can't for the life of me figure out how to get ant to see that library.  What am I doing wrong?

**The Error Message**

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/ec2-user/ant/ucp/build.xml:48: Problem: failed to create 
task or type antlib:com.salesforce:retrieve
Cause: The name is undefined.
```

**The Background**

I installed ant using `yum install ant` and then I dropped the Force.com Migration Tool (ant-salesforce.jar) into `/usr/share/ant/lib`.  I'm able to see this library when I run `ant -diagnostics`, but none of the tasks for that library (should be seeing deploy, retrieve, etc.).  I've uploaded a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f40a4cbc418df0329d91) with the full output from `ant -diagnostics`.

```
-------------------------------------------
 ANT_HOME/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
ant.home: /usr/share/ant
ant-bootstrap.jar (19837 bytes)
ant-salesforce.jar (3293054 bytes)
ant.jar (1942059 bytes)
ant-launcher.jar (18418 bytes)
```

After lots of googling and manual reading I tried the following to no avail (NB: the above diagnostics is without any of the below changes).  I know I'm missing something obvious :(

1. Setting $ANT_HOME `export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant`
2. Fiddling with permissions `chmod +x /usr/share/ant/lib/salesforce-jar`
3. Fiddling with groups `chown root:root /usr/share/ant/lib/salesforce-jar`
4. Passing in class with -lib `ant -lib /usr/share/ant/lib/salesforce-jar retrieve ...`
5. Passing in lib folder with -lib `ant -lib /usr/share/ant/lib retrieve ...`
6. Adding $ANT_HOME to $PATH `export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about keeping `ant-salesforce.jar` under `/home/ec2-user/ant/ucp` and then change the `taskdef` element to look like this:

```
<taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" classpath="ant-salesforce.jar" />
```

Run your build again and see if things look better. Having the JAR in the same folder as `build.xml` will help you eliminate issues with permissions.

Comment: Saweet!! Thank you for the tip.  That worked.  Are there any references out there that to help understand all the permissions that are in play to avoid this scenario? I'm at a loss to how the class can show up in the ant classpath, but never has it's tasks loaded.

Comment: Reason being these tasks are going to be used by some system processes for a CI tool.  Which I'm sure is going to bring this one back up again ... :(

Comment: running `ant -verbose` might get you some more insight into what might be amiss. That said, it can be very difficult to find out more about the causes of exceptions when the JVM interacts with the underlying filesystem, because the JVM can often hide the finer details and give you only a stacktrace from an exception under `java.io`.

Comment: you can use a local library even with a CI tool by eliciting the services of Ivy and a repository manager like [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). Since `ant-salesforce.jar` is a commercial artifact, you will have to set up an internal repository manager, upload the JAR to it and then once you have the Ivy configuration in place, your build will fetch the JAR from the repository manager and use it. You can avoid having to tamper with the base Ant setup too.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [@smooth_reggae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16380086/edit) was able to get things working while keeping ant-salesforce.jar in the default ant lib directory.  Seems like this should already be happening, but oh-well.

```
<taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml"
    classPath="${ant.library.dir}/ant-salesforce.jar"
    uri="antlib:com.salesforce"/>
```

Comment: Awesome, this makes much more sense to me then putting it in the ant home directory, thanks!

Comment: Where is ant.library.dir set? and what exactly is its value?

Comment: @flor lots of details on that in the question :)